# Error 302 when trying to redirect from API Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

Upon [redirecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PesdL.png) shows me the page being called and 302 error being shown. How do I handle this where it allows me to redirect to the page via API method and show an error message if the credentials are wrong. I would prefer to refrain from using `window.location.href` as passing in RedirectUrl doesn't work.

API method

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("Login")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromForm] LoginViewModel model)
{
    if (model.Username == "user" && model.Password == "password")
    {
        Redirect("/User/Index");
    }
    else return StatusCode(400, "Invalid user or password");
}
```

AJAX Call

```
$("#loginBtn").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/Account/Login',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#loginForm').serialize()
    })
        .done(function (data) {
        })
        .fail(function () {
                $('#errorMessage').append("Invalid username or password").show();
                $('#errorMessage').removeAttr('id');
            }
        });
});
```

---

Edit:
From Athanasios Kataras explanation, I decided play around with the error message instead. I came up with this solution:

```
$("#loginBtn").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/Account/Login',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#loginForm').serialize()
    })
        .done(function (data) {
        })
        .fail(function () {
                sessionStorage.setItem("error", "Error");
                location.reload();
            }
        });
});

if (sessionStorage.getItem("error") != null) {
    $('#errorMessage').html("Invalid username or password").show();
    sessionStorage.removeItem("error");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't redirect via XHR requests. When the 302 is returned, the browser will follow it at once and look for an ajax response at the new url.

If it's a full post back and not xhr/ajax request, it will redirect properly.

In the past you wouldn't even see the redirect but now it is there.

I don't see another way other than `window.location.href` to be honest.

Maybe though, you can get the status by using this, but I have bit checked it. It could be that in this way you can catch the 302 and handle it appropriately.

```
$.ajax( url [, settings ] )
    .always(function (jqXHR) {
        console.log(jqXHR.status);
 });
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation. I decided to go with a workaround with the error handling instead.

Comment: Glad I could help